# VBA Excel Need the inner text but not the tag the it also contains

Tags: excel, vba, tags, getelementsbytagname

I need to get the "4,499.00" in the span tag but not the  SEK part.

```
<span id="big-value" class=big-value"> <sup> SEK </sup> 4,499.00 </span>
```

I use

```
Recovered = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("span")(22).innertext
```

But it do not seem to work when the tag contains another tag. It get back both the SEK and 4,499.00 (Which it should but I do not know how to work around it). Any idea of how to work round this?

Comment: try this
<span id="big-value" class=big-value"><sup> SEK </sup></span> <span id="big-value" class=big-value">  4,499.00 </span>

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the *tag* information or parse the string to the extract the number. The code below uses a `Regexp` to do the later

*Your text*

```
Sub Test()
MsgBox CleanStr("<span id=""big-value"" class=big-value""""> <sup> SEK </sup> 4,499.00 </span>")
End Sub
```

*UDF to extract number*

```
Function CleanStr(StrIn As String) As String
Dim objRegex As Object
Dim objRegexMC As Object
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
     .Pattern = "[0-9,\.]+"
     If .Test(StrIn) Then
        Set objRegexMC = .Execute(StrIn)
        CleanStr = objRegexMC(0)
    Else
        CleanStr = "No Match"
    End If
End With
End Function
```